# Is it possible to reload Django application without stopping it?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django 1.11 Software as a service (Saas) application with one single postgresql database. When a new User is created, it automatically creates two tables associated to him. A part of the code:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    Client.objects.create(...attributes...)
    call_command('makemigrations', interactive=False)
    call_command('migrate', interactive=False)
```

But when I go the admin site, the new tables are not displayed, I need to stop and restart server. Is there a way to reload it without stopping the service ?

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: To see the databases in admin site you need to register them in admin.py as admin.site.register("Your Model"), if you want to do it in another file just import the admin package `from django.contrib import admin`

Comment: Are you sure you want `interactive=True` ???

Comment: @MatheusVeleci I have a function to list all the models of my application, So if I execute a second time this function, I should see the new models in admin site ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, actually I'm not sure to understand the interactive attribute...

Comment: @B.Mike as you are creating new tables, you need to register them to admin site. So if you have a function to register all the models in your application it should work!

Comment: @MatheusVeleci Thank you a lot for your help ! I also found an interesting link which talks about dynamic models and how to register it in admin site : https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Comment: Perfect! This is actually really interesting. Thank you for posting the Wiki link.